# How to add "<" ">" to element value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, cdata

I need to prepare XML for ceneo and I have to add

```xml
<![CDATA[text]]>
```

to all values like this:

```xml
<a name="Kod_producenta"><![CDATA[82981]]></a>
<a name="EAN"><![CDATA[5907640829815]]></a>
```

Not working part of my xslt:

```xml
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Producent'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('<![CDATA[', producer/@name, ']]>')"/>
</a>
```

I'm getting an error like:

> element type must not contain the '<' character

Comment: `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="a"/>` might help if the XSLT processor serializes the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never possible to write lexical markup directly in XSLT (except possibly using the disable-output-escaping hack, which only works under some circumstances). XSLT is designed to produce a tree of nodes, not lexical XML output, and the XDM data model defining that tree doesn't have any knowledge of CDATA.

The consumer of your XML really shouldn't care whether the text is in a CDATA section or not, but if they do, you can get it added at serialization time using `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="..."/>`